# print out all integer it can be divided by

Tags: java

I'm a beginner and I am having a really hard time while doing this program in java.
The question is:

> Write a program which asks user for an integer, and then prints out all integer it can be divided by. Example: if user enters 6, then result must be 1, 2 and 3.

Could you just give me some tips on, I want to try make it by my self, just confusing on beginning.

Comment: No. You need to try something first, you won't learn otherwise. Read the Java tutorials https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: I think its a easy one you can think and do it easily. please don't put your burden to other shoulders Thank you

Comment: The downvotes are unwarranted.    Sure this is a very basic problem, but given what the OP knows, and where he is stuck, it is hard to see how he could have asked a better question.

Comment: master G. I coded a sample answer https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yR5onlicJlOgJWuXllJlFbjB2iqGXwBX-WkOTF6FDU0/pub hope this would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

> Could you just give me some tips ...

Hint: break the problem down into parts; e.g.

1. Get a number of from the user
2. Compute the set of numbers that it is divisible by
3. Print the results.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this out. You may found your Solution and try to manipulate as your need. Thanks

```
class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int a = 10;
        Integer [] arr = new Integer[a/2];
        int j = 0;
        for(int i =1; i< a/2; i++){
            if(a % i == 0){
                arr[j++] = i;
            }
        }
        for(int k = 0; k< arr.length ; k++)
            System.out.println(arr[k]);
    }
}
```